# MongoDB C# Aggregation with LINQ

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation

I have a mongo object with these fields:

```
DateTime TimeStamp;
float    Value;
```

How can I get the aggregation pipeline, in C#, with LINQ, to get the minimum, maximum and average of Value over a specific timestamp range?

I have seen a few aggregation examples, but I don't quite get it. Having an example on a simple case like this would certainly (hopefully) make me understand it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use LINQ syntax which gets translated into Aggregation Framework's syntax. Assuming you have following `Model` class:

```
public class Model
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public float Value { get; set; }
}
```

you can use `where` to specify timestamp range and then use `group` with `null` as grouping key. MongoDB driver will translate `Min`, `Max` and `Average` from anonymous type into `$max`, `$min` and `$avg` from Aggregation Framework syntax

```
var q = from doc in Col.AsQueryable()
        where doc.Timestamp > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3)
        where doc.Timestamp < DateTime.Now.AddDays(3)
        group doc by (Model)null into gr
        select new
        {
            Avg = (double)gr.Average(x => x.Value),
            Min = gr.Min(x => x.Value),
            Max = gr.Max(x => x.Value)
        };

var result = q.First();
```

List of accumulators supported by MongoDB driver can be found [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/reference/driver/expressions/#accumulators).

EDIT: the `(Model)null` is required because the query has to be transformed to `$group` with `_id` set to `null` ([docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#group-by-null)) since you want to get one result with aggregates. Casting is required just for C# compiler purpose as doc is of type `Model`.

Comment: can you explain the '(Model) null' part? I don't understand the null keyword there

Comment: an additional question: is is possible to do something, below the where, like: let Value = doc.Value and then group Value in order to not carry around the rest of the object?

Comment: @Thomas explained the null part in my edited answer. You can read more here (http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/reference/driver/crud/linq/) about which LINQ operators are supported

Answer (score 3):

The aggregation for this is done in two steps:

1. [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) - Retrieve documents with `TimeStamp` value between some defined `minDate` and `maxDate`.
2. [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#accumulator-operator) - Group on null. This will put all documents in a single group so we can apply an accumulator function across everything from the step 1 $match. The accumulator functions you're looking for are `$min`, `$max`, and `$avg`.

---

```
IMongoCollection<Entity> collection = GetMyCollection();

DateTime minDate = default(DateTime); // define this yourself
DateTime maxDate = default(DateTime); // define this yourself

var match = new BsonDocument
{ {
    "$match", new BsonDocument
    { {
        "TimeStamp", new BsonDocument
        { {
            "$and", new BsonDocument
            {
                { "$gt", minDate },
                { "$lt", maxDate }
            }
        } }
    } }
} };

var group = new BsonDocument
{ {
    "$group", new BsonDocument
    {
        { "_id", BsonNull.Value },
        { "min", new BsonDocument { { "$min", "Value" } } },
        { "max", new BsonDocument { { "$max", "Value" } } },
        { "avg", new BsonDocument { { "$avg", "Value" } } },
    }
} };

var result = collection.Aggregate(PipelineDefinition<Entity, BsonDocument>.Create(match, group)).Single();

double min = result["min"].AsDouble;
double max = result["max"].AsDouble;
double avg = result["avg"].AsDouble;
```